# How to parse JSON created from XML response of SOAP WS?

Tags: json, node.js, xml, xmldom

I need help in parsing a JSON created from an XML response of a SOAP web-service in NodeJS. I want a JSON array of `notifications`.

XML is as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getNotificationsResponse xmlns:ns2="---url---">
         <return>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Testing Notitfications</body>
               <created>1498798404874</created>
               <gpsAlt>1.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>1.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>1.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>253</messageId>
               <priority>INFORMATIONAL</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC0</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test Notification</subject>
               <updated>1498798404874</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Test notitfication</body>
               <created>1498797535714</created>
               <gpsAlt>0.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>0.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>0.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>244</messageId>
               <priority>HIGH</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC_1234</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test</subject>
               <updated>1498797535714</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Testing Notitfications</body>
               <created>1498794764538</created>
               <gpsAlt>1.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>1.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>1.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>239</messageId>
               <priority>INFORMATIONAL</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC0</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test Notification</subject>
               <updated>1498794764538</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Testing Notitfications</body>
               <created>1498794760123</created>
               <gpsAlt>1.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>1.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>1.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>234</messageId>
               <priority>INFORMATIONAL</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC0</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test Notification</subject>
               <updated>1498794760123</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
         </return>
      </ns2:getNotificationsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using xmldom node module.
My code is as follows, but it doesn't give a proper response.

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data.response, 'text/xml');
var valueXML = doc.getElementsByTagName('return');
var temp = valueXML[0].getElementsByTagName("notifications")[0];
var output = temp.getElementsByTagName("nextSibling")._node.childNodes.parentNode
```

Comment: how about `valueXML[0].children`

Comment: @ShanilFernando, it returns undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const fs = require('fs')

const xml = fs.readFileSync('so.xml', 'utf-8')
const template = {
    notifications: ['//notifications', {
        ackRequired: 'ackRequired',
        body: 'body',
        created: 'created',
        gpsAlt: 'number(gpsAlt)'
    }]
}

const result = transform(xml, template)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

And output:

```
{
  "notifications": [
    {
      "ackRequired": "false",
      "body": "Testing Notitfications",
      "created": "1498798404874",
      "gpsAlt": 1
    },
    {
      "ackRequired": "false",
      "body": "Test notitfication",
      "created": "1498797535714",
      "gpsAlt": 0
    },
    {
      "ackRequired": "false",
      "body": "Testing Notitfications",
      "created": "1498794764538",
      "gpsAlt": 1
    },
    {
      "ackRequired": "false",
      "body": "Testing Notitfications",
      "created": "1498794760123",
      "gpsAlt": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I just add a few fields in template to test. You can add more base on what you need.

Comment: what if I don't know fields?

Comment: @DarshanaAhalpara i wrote this package for the purpose of transforming xml to json but you will have to write template yourself (you know the format of the input). But if that's not the case, you may have to find another package for this.

Comment: Also, can you mark it as answer if it works for you :)

Comment: your module worked fine with Windows, but when I tried on Red Hat it gives me error as g++ build failed. I'm not having rights to install gcc compiler on red hat system, is there any other way by which I can make it work?

Comment: Also, it requires gcc 4.9 (which is default in most distros now i think).

Answer (score 2):

Try This. You can map it as you want in the JSON. I just show you the direction.

[Working example in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xrWNKB?editors=1111)

```js
var response = `
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getNotificationsResponse xmlns:ns2="---url---">
         <return>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Testing Notitfications</body>
               <created>1498798404874</created>
               <gpsAlt>1.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>1.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>1.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>253</messageId>
               <priority>INFORMATIONAL</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC0</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test Notification</subject>
               <updated>1498798404874</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Test notitfication</body>
               <created>1498797535714</created>
               <gpsAlt>0.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>0.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>0.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>244</messageId>
               <priority>HIGH</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC_1234</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test</subject>
               <updated>1498797535714</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Testing Notitfications</body>
               <created>1498794764538</created>
               <gpsAlt>1.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>1.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>1.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>239</messageId>
               <priority>INFORMATIONAL</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC0</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test Notification</subject>
               <updated>1498794764538</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
            <notifications>
               <ackRequired>false</ackRequired>
               <body>Testing Notitfications</body>
               <created>1498794760123</created>
               <gpsAlt>1.0</gpsAlt>
               <gpsLat>1.0</gpsLat>
               <gpsLong>1.0</gpsLong>
               <messageId>234</messageId>
               <priority>INFORMATIONAL</priority>
               <senderClientId>PMC0</senderClientId>
               <status>SENT</status>
               <subject>Test Notification</subject>
               <updated>1498794760123</updated>
               <userId>1</userId>
               <userLogin>ipics</userLogin>
            </notifications>
         </return>
      </ns2:getNotificationsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`;
    
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/xml');
var valueXML = doc.getElementsByTagName('return');
var temps = valueXML[0].children;
var nortifications=[];

for (var i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
    var temp = temps[i].children;
    var obj = {};
    
    for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
        var property = temp[j];
       
        obj[property.localName] = property.innerHTML;
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    nortifications.push(obj);
}
```

Output:

```
{"ackRequired":"false","body":"Testing Notitfications","created":"1498798404874","gpsAlt":"1.0","gpsLat":"1.0","gpsLong":"1.0","messageId":"253","priority":"INFORMATIONAL","senderClientId":"PMC0","status":"SENT","subject":"Test Notification","updated":"1498798404874","userId":"1","userLogin":"ipics"}  
{"ackRequired":"false","body":"Test notitfication","created":"1498797535714","gpsAlt":"0.0","gpsLat":"0.0","gpsLong":"0.0","messageId":"244","priority":"HIGH","senderClientId":"PMC_1234","status":"SENT","subject":"Test","updated":"1498797535714","userId":"1","userLogin":"ipics"}
{"ackRequired":"false","body":"Testing Notitfications","created":"1498794764538","gpsAlt":"1.0","gpsLat":"1.0","gpsLong":"1.0","messageId":"239","priority":"INFORMATIONAL","senderClientId":"PMC0","status":"SENT","subject":"Test Notification","updated":"1498794764538","userId":"1","userLogin":"ipics"} 
{"ackRequired":"false","body":"Testing Notitfications","created":"1498794760123","gpsAlt":"1.0","gpsLat":"1.0","gpsLong":"1.0","messageId":"234","priority":"INFORMATIONAL","senderClientId":"PMC0","status":"SENT","subject":"Test Notification","updated":"1498794760123","userId":"1","userLogin":"ipics"}
```

Comment: property.innerHTML gives undefined.

Comment: @DarshanaAhalpara Check the console output [https://jsfiddle.net/48qjec55/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/48qjec55/3/). I don't get any errors

Comment: I get the html tags in property. but when trying to fire property.innerHTML it gives undefined.

Comment: what do you mean by "fire property.innerHTML"?

Comment: When I'm trying to get value from property.innerHTML.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this? or you have already solved the problem? Any way try `co.sole.log(property)` and check `property` variable. and please note that in  `var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/xml');` I changed `data.response` to `respond` since I don't have access to the data variable, and passed the XML directly as a string. Check these two places. I tested before answering, It worked fine. I created a codepen for you, check it in the answer

Comment: Yes, I found solution for this problem. When I cosnoled property.localName i got <ackRequired>false</ackRequired> kind of output but when I tried for property.innerHTML it returns undefined.